# jQuery & CSS: Custom zoom function... almost there

Tags: jquery, css, zooming, positioning

I've got a small and simple zoom function that fades in an overlay and then resizes and repositions an image centered in the browser window above said overlay...

You can checkout a page I setup for this problem [here](http://benjibee.com/voila/), I didn't try *jFiddling* this one. If you move your browser window the image doesn't move with the rest of the content, but the idea behind the zoom works perfectly well. Thanks in advance for any advice!

**CSS:** *As I've got it now, it all works so long as I define the image's position as absolute and define a starting top and left position:*

```
#image{
    display:none; // faded in
    position:absolute;
    top:14em;
    left:30em;
    z-index:999999; // stay above overlay
}
```

**jQuery:** *And here is the jQuery function in it's full:*

```
    $("#display a").toggle(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    overlay = $("#overlay");
    image = $('#image');

            // Grab original sizes and positions for
            // calculations and zooming back out...

    o_width = image.width();
    o_height = image.height();
    o_left = image.css('left');
    o_top = image.css('top');

            // Define new width and calculate
            // new height from that...

    var n_width = 1024;
    var n_height = (n_width/o_width*o_height)

            // Grab window dimensions to center image
            // then calculate top and left offset...

    var w_height = $(window).height();
    var w_width = $(window).width();

    var left = (w_width-n_width)/2;
    var top = (w_height-n_height)/2;

    overlay.fadeTo(500,0.8);

    image.animate({
    left: left,
    top: top,
    height: n_height,
    width: n_width
      }, 300);

},function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    overlay.fadeOut(500);

    image.animate({
    left: o_left,
    top: o_top,
    height: o_height,
    width: o_width
      }, 300);
});
```

Comment: I suggest viewing in a WebKit browser such as Chrome or Safari as I have not yet tested my page in Firefox or Opera. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to test it myself:

For the "`#display`" DIV you have "`float: right;`". Try changing it to "`float: left;`".

or:

You could change it to "`position: absolute;`" and place it exactly where you want it (using "`top`" and "`left`") in its containing DIV "`#content`".

Comment: To be totally honest, I'm not sure what this has do to with my question, but I may be reading it wrong.

Comment: The "#display" DIV moves left and right as you resize the window and overlaps the small thumbnails if the window is too narrow. This is because it is "float: right;". I thought this is what you were alluding to. If not, could you describe the problem a bit better and I'll try to see what I can do.